# Question Regarding Full-Rated (100%-Rated) Circuit Breakers

Tags: power

When specifying circuit breakers, it’s customary that breakers protecting down stream equipment and feeder conductors should be rated at no more than 80% of their maximum rated load current downstream at the bus voltage for the devices/feeders.

But I’ve come across applications where 100%-rated breakers are used/specified. These are usually in high voltage power distribution scenarios.

I understand that using 100% rated breakers permits the use of smaller downstream feeder conductors. But does anyone know where using such breakers makes sense? They are more expensive than regular breakers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found this excellent blog from Schneider Electric on the differance between 100% rated and 80% rated breakers. [This is a link](http://sedatacenters.com/resources/videos/podcasts/100-percent-vs-80-percent-powerpact-circuit-breakers/) to the Podcast mentioned in the blog.

> **Clearing up Confusion over 80% vs. 100%-rated Circuit Breakers**
>
> Paul Desmond | June 12, 2014
>
> 1. When building or upgrading a data center, at some point you need to
>    make a decision about which circuit breakers to use. While on the face
>    of it that may seem to be a simple decision – use the one that’s the
>    best fit for your load – in fact it can become significantly more
>    complicated if you don’t have a thorough understanding of breaker
>    ratings and what they mean.
> 2. In the circuit breaker world there’s been some misunderstanding about
>    the terms “100%-rated” and “80%-rated” circuit breakers. To dispel the
>    confusion, Schneider Electric’s Mohamed Shishani put together a short
>    (less than 10 minutes) podcast that does a nice job explaining the
>    issue.
> 3. Understanding the difference between the two begins with a reading of
>    the 2011 National Electric Code. Section 210.20(A) of the code
>    basically says that a circuit breaker for a branch circuit must be
>    rated such that it can handle the noncontinuous load plus 125% of the
>    continuous load. (*A continuous load is one where the maximum current is
>    expected to continue for 3 hours or more*.) In other words, the breaker
>    needs an extra 25% capacity of the continuous load for headroom. That,
>    of course, means you need a larger, more expensive breaker.
> 4. There is, however, an exception. *When the circuit breaker is listed
>    for operation at 100% of its rating, the additional 25% requirement
>    goes away*. Instead, the device simply has to be able to handle the sum
>    of the continuous load and the noncontinuous load.
> 5. Now, in practice, you may think it will nearly always make sense to
>    buy 100%-rated breakers and call it a day. But as the podcast points
>    out, it’s not quite that simple.
> 6. *You need to do some load calculations to determine if your loads are
>    primarily continuous or noncontinuous*. If all your loads are
>    non-continuous, you don’t have to worry about the 125% requirement so
>    you can just size your breakers for 100% of your load. In that case,
>    standard, 80%-rated breakers will be more economical.
> 7. If you do have some continuous loads, Shishani says it’s best to
>    segment your circuits so they’re all the same flavor, either
>    continuous or noncontinuous. Then the choice of breaker will become
>    clear.
> 8. Where you can’t do that, you need to determine the load on each branch
>    circuit, then calculate the required ampere rating you need for each
>    circuit breaker. The rating will be higher for the standard, 80%-rated
>    breakers because you need to allow for an extra 25% capacity on the
>    continuous loads. That may make the 100% breakers the more economical
>    choice. On the other hand, if you need room for growth, that may also
>    play into the equation.
> 9. The podcast goes through a few sample calculations to help you
>    understand all the tradeoffs. Check it out to see if you can save some
>    money the next time you need to buy circuit breakers.